# I send from my MIST unnamed wallet 25 ETH to Yobit. Are my coins lost?

Tags: mist

I send from my unnamed Contract wallet 25 ETH to Yobit. In the etherchain it sayed and shown as Internal Transactions.

So does discriminate between unnamed and base-wallets? The 25 ETHER It never reacted my Yobit Wallet :-(
A second dipost of 20 Ether from my mist base-wallet did come true.
What happened to the 25 Ether?  Why di9d my stupt wallet let me send Ether if its not possible to yobit.
See:  http://etherscan.io/tx/0xcbb81a6aaa5687fbc1ae53a1a86f79b0e2fa982019964db3fe93f841174f104f

Are my coins lost? Can youbit still get my coins?

Comment: See these conversation https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/issues/82 . TL;DR Some exchanges do not support receiving ether from a contract wallet. You should contact Yobit support and point them to the internal transaction, and say that you used the wrong wallet.